# Is "account optional" feature available for PayPal's Subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, credit-card, paypal-subscriptions

We can see that "account optional" is available on Paypal's sketch:
[image]

Yet testing in the sandbox the option does not appear:
[image]

Is that due to the sandbox environment or is "account optional" feature not available for Suscriptions  ?

Thank you for your support.

Edit: It also appear here that subscription should support credit card:
[image]

Comment: Not sure that "account optional" is available in subscriptions. Because when testing regular payments in a sandbox mode, it's possible to pay with a card without logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Guest Checkout is not available with PayPal Subscriptions.

If you want to manage recurring profiles with direct credit cards you'll need to add PayPal Pro w/ Recurring Payments.  Then you can build those types of subscriptions with a custom checkout and the APIs (or configure it in a platform/plugin that integrates it for you.)

Comment: If so your documentation should be updated. See edit.
Paypal had lost our business yet thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: Well, yeah that's interesting.  I know my answer is correct for PayPal Standard and Classic Express Checkout APIs, but that graphic should makes it look like the REST APIs would allow it.  I do think that's a graphical mistake, but I'm going to double check with my contacts at PayPal.

Comment: I was able to verify that the Guest Checkout feature is indeed not available here, and they are going to get that image updated.